# Rails 4.2 has_many through in-place editing nested form with xeditable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, form-submit, frontend, nested-forms, x-editable

I have the following list of models in a `Rails 4.2` app:

- User
- Company
- Marketplace

The associations look like the following:

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

**Company.rb**

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :company_marketplaces
  has_many :marketplaces, through: :company_marketplaces

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :marketplaces, update_only: true
end
```

Marketplace.rb

```
class Marketplace < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :company_marketplaces
  has_many :companies, through: :company_marketplaces
end
```

I am trying to build a **form** to allow **adding/removing marketplaces** to a company with the help of in-place editing library `x-editable`. I was able to allow **adding** new marketplaces from an existing list but it fails on the **removing** because no data is submitted.

This is the relevant part of the view:

**index.html.slim**

```
        td
          = link_to company.marketplaces.join(", "), "", data: { :"name" => "marketplaces_attributes" , :"xeditable" => "true", :"url" => admin_agents_company_path(company), :"pk" => company.id, :"model" => "company", :"type" => "checklist", :"placement" => "right", :"value" => company.marketplaces.join(", "), :"source" => "/marketplaces" }, class: "editable editable-click"
```

And `companies_controller.rb#update` method looks like the following:

**companies_controller.rb**

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @company.update(company_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @company, notice: 'Company was successfully updated.' }
      format.json
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

Most of the resources I was able to find do not deal with in-place editing or use `fields_for` to work with `nested_forms`.

Is there a solution to handle **adding/removing** `has_many:` `through:` associated objects in a form without relying on `fields_for`?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can provide **marketplaces_attributes** in params.

Example from: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts
end

params = { member: {
  name: 'joe', posts_attributes: [
    { title: 'Kari, the awesome Ruby documentation browser!' },
    { title: 'The egalitarian assumption of the modern citizen' },
    { title: '', _destroy: '1' } # this will be ignored
  ]
}}

member = Member.create(params[:member])
member.posts.length # => 2
member.posts.first.title # => 'Kari, the awesome Ruby documentation browser!'
member.posts.second.title # => 'The egalitarian assumption of the modern citizen'
```

Read more examples in that link above